# Trying to find what driver my printer is currently using on OS X

Tags: macos, printing, driver

I have two Macs, and one (with Mavericks) is working with a Sharp printer no problem, the other Mac (also with Mavericks) on the same printer cannot print to it.

The mac having the problem can see the print can add it, and for all intents purposes it believes it is printing to it. I want to confirm what driver each Mac is using and I cannot locate that specifically. I have looked at all the drivers on each machine and they both look to have the same driver options on each computer.

So how to I tell which driver they are each currently using? In case it is a simple as they are using different drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari, enter the address (without quotes) "localhost:631" to view your CUPS administration page.  The tabs along the top are fairly self explanatory.

Administration > Manage Printers > Select the printer.  This will show you the driver that it is currently set to use.

If you instead receive a message that the web interface is currently disabled you will need to first enter this line into Terminal and press return.

```
cupsctl WebInterface=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Printers & Scanners**, select your printer and click **Options & Supplies**. Your printer identifier and driver version is shown on the sheet.